# Can't type anything in inputs or textareas

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input

I have a problem: I've add a Jquery UI drag-n-drop widget to my page, but after that I can't type anything into inputs or textareas.

I use jQuery 1.4.2 and jQuery UI 1.8rc3, and tiny_mce for convert textareas into WYSIWUG editor (I've tried to disable tiny_mce). When I put `$("input").click(
function(){
alert('clicked!');
});` - it's working(I have an alert).

When I get focused to any input I even can't refresh page by F5 and go to the next element by Tab key.

There's a page: http://cms.reactive.by/test.htm (click to clip2net.com/clip/m7787/1269022358-clip-3kb.png to see that jQuery UI is workong)

And yes.. there's no errors in FireBug.

I hope You can help me to understand what's wrong with this code.

Comment: HTML with XHTML doctype? http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcms.reactive.by%2Ftest.htm Fix the doctype to be a HTML doctype (more recommended), or rewrite HTML as XHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WYSIWYG editors all fail because most of the JavaScript files the editor tries to load, for example:

- http://cms.reactive.by/test_files/themes/advanced/editor_template.js
- http://cms.reactive.by/test_files/plugins/imagemanager/editor_plugin.js

return

```
По вопросам, связанным с работой <b>Reactive.CMS</b> 
обращайтесь по адресу: support@cms.reactive.by.
```

I guess that's a error message?

The Firefox error console complains about every such file with a syntax error, should be easy enough to sort out.

Comment: I'm so sorry for this. Fixed. Please, try again

Comment: @dev no problem. You still seem to get a lot of failed JavaScript loadds, all trying to load the index page. Check the error console. I suspect it's these: `src='javascript:""'`

Comment: @dev the errors are gone now, I can't really see why the textarea is not initializing. In Firefox, though, the CSS styles are not coming up because (I think) their content-type is not `text/css`. Maybe that's part of the problem.

Comment: Oh, I've solved my problem. That was jquery.hotkeys.js, jQ and jQUI isn't crime :) When I've tried to create a guest user in CMS for U I've looked at the end of code - there was jquery.hotkeys.js :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by defining either maxlength="20" or readonly fields..